# Displaying listview in Hierarchy

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

This might be a noob question as I am new to nativescript.

I am looking for a way to recursively display listview.

Currently, I am making an app to take surveys. I have a list of questions to be displayed and based on the selection I have to display child questions inside those questions.

E.g. In the following example. If a user checks Pune. The sub-question is rendered and if that is selected, The sub-question inside is displayed

Select Preferred cities:

- Banglore

  - Required Transportation
  - Required Shifting

    - Required advanced payment
- Mumbai

  - Required Shifting

    - Required advanced payment
- Pune

  - Required Work from home

    - Required advanced payment

Comment: have two list views and on click event play around with data and visibility of second list view

Comment: @VikasAcharya I tried it, the height of the row doesn't increase dynamically